# Haskell `callProcess` causes sometimes problems with `locale`

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

In a function `callProcess` is used to check the locale (afterward lualatex is run and wants to read the locale).

```
f1 a b = do 
    -- check for locale 
    loc <- callIO $ callProcess "locale" []
    putStrLn "writePDF2text locale " ]
```

If a program is run with `ghci` (precisely `stack exec ghci`) I get the expected output:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

If it is run under `stack test`, I get

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
SSG                > locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
SSG                > locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
SSG                > LANG=en-US
SSG                > LANGUAGE=en_US:en
SSG                > LC_CTYPE="en-US"
SSG                > LC_NUMERIC="en-US"
SSG                > LC_TIME="en-US"
SSG                > LC_COLLATE="en-US"
SSG                > LC_MONETARY="en-US"
SSG                > LC_MESSAGES="en-US"
SSG                > LC_PAPER="en-US"
SSG                > LC_NAME="en-US"
SSG                > LC_ADDRESS="en-US"
SSG                > LC_TELEPHONE="en-US"
SSG                > LC_MEASUREMENT="en-US"
SSG                > LC_IDENTIFICATION="en-US"
SSG                > LC_ALL=en-US
```

The same result is produced with the same program installed and run without `Stack`.

Any explanation for this difference in behavior? More important, how to avoid the issue and assure that the next process called sees a proper environment?

Answer (score 1):

In locale output, values with quotes are automatic, values without are set in environment. In you second print, there it this

> LC_ALL=en-US

So stack test defines the LC_ALL=en-US somewhere which probably interpreted as latin1 encoding. You should be looking what defines the LC_ALL environment variable.

Ps

> More important, how to avoid the issue and assure that the next process called sees a proper environment?

It is all just environment variables, so you need to (un)set them either with callProcess arguments or permanently with corresponding API

Comment: Thank you - very useful to understand the meaning of the quotes. I fear it is lualatex which set the LC_ALL value or some part of stack (unlikely), or ?

Comment: I tried to find where in the process the locale was set to en-US; while checking the problem disappeared.